# Подключение шрифтов

Tags: html5, css3

Подключил шрифты (Proxima Nova) через СSS, кириллица есть у это шрифта, а вот на странице русский текст все равно не меняется и остается Times, а с английским все нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Просто кириллица у шрифта это отдельная тема, а наличие кириллицы в подключенных вами конкретных файлах проверяли? В интернетах, бывает, распространяют шрифты без кириллицы, даже если она существует

Comment: Есть точно в файле

Comment: а какой нюанс с кириллицей

Comment: Укажите пример разметки. Вы проверяли, загружается ли ваш шрифт или системный?

Comment: ну в фотошопе все работает. Как еще проверить?